# Intuition for Poincaré duality and Cap product

Tags: algebraic-topology, intuition

Can you provide me with any intuition behind the Cap product of a cohomology class and a homology class? What is its geometric meaning? Can you also give me an intuition why the Poincaré duality is true?

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia page? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_product  It describes the cap product as a type of partial evaluation function.  Regarding why Poincare duality is true, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14467/poincare-duality-reference/14469#14469 , which you can interpret in terms of cap products if you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure this is the geometric meaning you want to have, but it's very helpful for me to understand Poincare duality: I think that the baby version of Poincare duality is the duality for planar graph (or a graph embedded in a general $2$-dimensional surface). Given a planar drawing of $G$, then the dual graph $G^*$ is a graph which has a vertex for each plane region of $G$, and an edge for each edge in $G$ joining two neighboring regions, according  to [Dual graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph). Of course, the plane is $2$-dimension. Therefore, face in $G$, which is $2$-dimensional, corresponds to a vertex in $G*$, which is $2-2=0$-dimensional. Edge in $G$, which is $1$-dimensional, corresponds to an edge in $G*$, which is $2-1=1$-dimensional. And vertex in $G$, which is $0$-dimensional, corresponds to a face in $G*$, which is $2-0=2$-dimensional. On the other hand, $|V(G)|=|F(G^*)|$, $|E(G)|=|E(G^*)|$, and  $|V(G^*)|=|F(G)|$, which is Poincare duality.

Comment: But, if we think of graph as a cell complex, the dimension of the top cell is 1, right? To get the dual of a graph, we should associate 1-cells (edges) with (1-1=0)-cells and, 0-cells(vertices) with (1-0=1)-cells, as per the discussion given [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality#Dual_cell_structures). Or, otherwise if we consider the graph together with the the faces _filled in_, then I understand the correspondence vertices -> faces, etc. Are we consider graphs with their faces _filled in_?